# Cannot Access Elements (iframe) using the cypress suggested selector

Tags: automation, cypress

I have a difficulties with some content of the web-page when I am trying to discover the element

For example some part of the web-page is blocked by the following:

```
[data-testid=shell-content]
```

Any idea what could possibly cause following? [image]

In the browser, the page isn't blocked and (all buttons) can be accessed by the keyboard or mouse.

Tried to upgrade to the lates version, still the same problem.

Comment: There's not enough information here to give any concise answer. What does the page look like? What is the rendered HTML? What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was described against the iframe, it has to be handled in a similar way in order to access the elements

```
cy.enter('iframe[data-testid="iframe-content"]').then((getBody) => {
    getBody().find('[data-test-id="create-user-button"]').click();
```

please note that name `shell-content` could be different to what was name in your project.